# Index Error : list index out of range in python code

Tags: python

This is my Python code for merge sort, and I can't understand why I am getting an `IndexError` on line 23 .

line 23 does not give an error if put before the `for` loop but in the `for` loop it says `list index out of range`. :(

```
from math import floor

def merge_sort(a,p,r):
 if p < r:
  q = (p+r)/2
  merge_sort(a,p,q)
  merge_sort(a,q+1,r)
  merge(a,p,q,r)

def merge(A,p,q,r):
 n1 = q - r +1
 n2 = r - q
 L = []
 R = []
 #print n1
 for i in range (1,n1):
  L.append(a[p+i-1])
 for j in range (1,n2):
  R.append(a[q+j])
 L.append(10000)
 R.append(10000)
 i,j=0,0

 for k in range (p,r):
  if L[i] <= R [j]: # This is where the error occurs
   A[k] = L[i]
   i = i + 1
  else :  
   A[k] = R[j]
   j = j + 1



a=[1,4,9,8,2,3,8,2,9]
merge_sort(a,1,len(a)) 
print a
```

Comment: Which is line 23? Can you indicate it with a comment?

Comment: your indentation is messed up, you should use four spaces for indentation.

Comment: why do you need `L.append(10000)` operation?

Comment: oh man reading this is a nightmare

Comment: well if one of the list is shorter it will go out of bounds.. I think you should check for the case when one of the lists is empty at which point you should just add all of its contents to the result list instead of incrementing the index continuously..

Answer (score 0):

This is not python, this is Pascal with Python syntax.

Here is implementation of merge sorting algo (based on [Merge sort wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort)):

```
def merge_sort(data):
    if len(data) <= 1:
        return data

    middle = len(data) / 2

    left = merge_sort(data[0:middle])
    right = merge_sort(data[middle:])

    return merge(left, right)


def merge(left, right):
    result = []

    while left or right:
        if left and right:
            if left[0] <= right[0]:
                result.append(left.pop(0))
                continue

            result.append(right.pop(0))
            continue

        if left:
            result.append(left.pop(0))
        elif right:
            result.append(right.pop(0))

    return result


data = [1, 4, 9, 8, 2, 3, 8, 2, 9]
result = merge_sort(data)

assert len(data) == len(result)

print result
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the commenters/other posters, this script has a Python syntax (apart from indentations that are not the customary 4 spaces...) but is *far* from Pythonic...

Anyhow, for your problem: it looks like the issue shows up in `merge` when `(p,q,r)=(1,2,3)`. In that case, `n1=0` and `n2=1`. Looping on `range(1,n1)` will get you nothing, therefore your `L` will only have 1 element (the `10000` you append to it outside the loop).

Now, when you reach the `for k in range (p,r)` loop:

- on the first iteration, `k=p=1`, `L[0] <= R[0]` and you add `1` to `i`, so `i`=1
- on the second iteration, you try to access `L[i]`, ie `L[1]`, which isn't defined. Hence, the `IndexError`.

A few advices:

- Learn how to use a debugger. Lots of IDEs come with some implementation, it really helps.
- Remember that lists start with an index of 0. It's something you tend to forget when you come from another language.